# Ask CLI: Simulate not resolving skill, returning IntentForDifferentSkill error

Tags: aws-lambda, command-line-interface, alexa-skills-kit, ask-cli

I'm trying to use the Ask CLI simulator to test my skill and nothing I input invokes it correctly. The test simulator on the website works fine, but when I try to use a command like ask simulate -l en-US -t "ask test skill what can I say" I get back "This utterance did not resolve to any intent in your skill. Please invoke your skill and try again with a different utterance or update your interaction model to include this utterance before testing again.". It doesn't matter if I append Alexa, insert commas, or even leave off everything except the "ask test skill", it always returns the same error. This is the same account I am logged in on the skill, and like I said previously the web test interface works just fine. I've tried searching online for "IntentForDifferentSkill" but get very few results.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you run

`ask simulate -l en-US -t "alexa open test skill"`

does that work?

If you're still getting the `IntentForDifferentSkill` error try passing in the

```
--force-new-session
```

flag which I found resolved the issue for me.